# Can Homebrew run on Apple ARM processors?

Tags: python, node.js, macos, homebrew, apple-silicon

I ordered a MacBook Pro equipped with an M1 ARM processor. Will I be able to run [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and install dev tools like Python, Node etc..?

Comment: Update: There is a PR open here https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/7857

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Now Homebrew fully supports Apple Silicon https://brew.sh/2021/02/05/homebrew-3.0.0/

Answer (score 3):

As said [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/9075), They will do more support on ARM CPU's

But, as said [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/9066) and more specifically [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/f5b71af6de4103de37364aec10c7be524760cd51/docs/Homebrew-on-Linux.md):

> Homebrew can run on 32-bit ARM (Raspberry Pi and others) and 64-bit ARM (AArch64), but no binary packages (bottles) are available. Support for ARM is on a best-effort basis. Pull requests are welcome to improve the experience on ARM platforms.

You may need to install your own Ruby using your system package manager, a PPA, or rbenv/ruby-build as we no longer distribute a Homebrew Portable Ruby for ARM.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's supported but using Rosetta.
Just put this prefix before the install homebrew command

> arch -x86_64

the final command should look like this (from https://brew.sh)

> arch -x86_64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

And every time you use brew you would have to use it with the prefix above.

Option 2:
There is an alternative, opening your terminal using Rosetta. I have not tried it but should give the same results without using the prefix.

[image]

Comment: I duplicated iterm to "iTerm Rosetta" and set this on to open with Rosetta. Could setup my entire Rails, Ruby + React Native, node, etc env with no problems. Brew running smoothly and thing are waaayyy faster

Answer (score 0):

partial support for packages and more coming with the
most recent instructions I've found at https://github.com/mikelxc/Workarounds-for-ARM-mac Homebrew [issue 7857](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/7857) mentioned above has a list of compatible packages that appears to be updating as more info comes; it appears that yes it does and there is steady progress to bring improved compatibility over the coming days, weeks, months, etc. I'm guessing the pace will accelerate over time as they integrated this into their CI workflow just a few days ago